# Do some people gain high immunity genetically?

Tags: common-cold, immune-system

I've seen many people who live in the same environmental conditions as that of mine but they never got infected by cold. For example my father would get cold only one or two times a year but I get infected by cold nearly every month. Not only this there is an old friend of mine whom I've never seen sick. When we were young he always asked me why do you get sick so often whereas he would never be sick.

Do some people gain high immunity genetically?

Comment: From the help section: Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much. All of your questions, even being split apart, are very broad and far reaching.

Comment: What affects immunity in humans is still too broad. Answering would consist in sumarizing all know litterature on this subject.

Comment: @Shlublu I've deleted the broad portion. Now this question is also of yes/no type. The answer would be of one word, either yes or no.